# Showing HTML page in one page without scrollbars, no matter the screen size

Tags: html, css

I am making a HTML email that a clients suddenly want to be shown as a one-pager without scrollbars. I have edited the wrapper to 'height:100vh', but it still has scrollbars.

I want to know, how would i go about and make this page appear as a one pager without scrollbars in all different screen heights?

```
    <body>
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper" width="600" align="center">
            <!-- Header image -->
            <table class="section header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td class="column center">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <img src="./media/header2.png" alt="picsum" width="600" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="section main" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">
                        <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <img src="./media/main-image1.png" alt="picsum" width="600"/>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="firstparagraph">
                                        <p class="comfortaaquote font40"> You will be OK... </p><br>
                                            <span class="marck"> Sweetheart</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <p class="comfortaatext center2">A lady is reassuring her dog everything will be OK in the veterinary hospital in Hanoi, Vietnam while the vet nurse are busy working in the background</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                        <div class="days-counter">
                                            <img class="steps" src="./media/counter.png" alt="picsum" width="300" />
                                            <div class="text-block"><p>14</p></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <img class="submit" src="./media/submit.png" alt="picsum" width="300" />
                                        <br>
                                        <br>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- bottom part-->
            <!-- footer part-->
            <table class="section bottom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <img src="./media/bottom.png" alt="picsum" width="600" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

should i be targeting the `height:100vh` to the body or the wrapper?

thank you

Comment: The only way I can think of for doing this is to set the zoom or scale property based on the available window area compared to the size of your table, but this would need js and most email clients would probably block js so I don't think this is possible

Comment: We don't have your images, so the html won't help that much as we can't know the height it will take. I think you'll have to control the size of your images to accomplish this, but even then it'd be difficult as you should worry with different resolutions and mobile view.

Comment: thats the thing, i want the whole content of the page to resize so it'll fit the current screen resolution or viewport of the email. it is already a responsive design, i think that making the wrapper follow the size of the screen, all the divs inside would follow the wrapper. right?

Comment: Not all email clients handle all css properties well. Anyway, did you remember to set all margins and border-spacings to 0? Things like that aren't 0 by default, and add to the total height.

Comment: I didn't test for myself, but as you are setting the width to 600, I think it'll not resize. I've always used percentage values in these cases, as well as `div`, not `table`.

Comment: the width is not the issue here, its resizing nicely, but i just want the height of the page to accommodate the size of the browser it is displayed on.